# R2DBC can not read the URL of oracle database

Tags: spring, kotlin, oracle11g, properties, spring-data-r2dbc

I try to config the oracle's connection by using application.properties file but it gives me an IllegalArgumentException with message "Invalid URL: r2dbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", it was fine when I set with the MySql URL. Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
spring.r2dbc.username=account
spring.r2dbc.password=account
```

please give me an explanation or solution for this, thank you.

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml or build.gradle file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try with

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:oracle:thin://localhost:1521:orcl
```

Comment: oh dear, you've saved my day. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm using xepdb1 service instead of XE or orcl. What should be the url then?

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to format the connection URL correctly. There is a lot of contradictory and outdated information that is no longer valid.

Right now (oracle-r2dbc 1.1.1, r2dbc-spi 1.0.0, spring-data-r2dbc 3.1.3) it’s correct to connect like this:

```
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:oracle://db_host:1521/db_service_name
    username: db_username
    password: db_password
```

Please note - there is no **:thin:** in path and SID/ServiceName placed after slash.